# Why does Plaxo Mac OS X sync use desktop client instead of Exchange?

Tags: macos, exchange-server, plaxo

I'm wondering why Plaxo makes its users download a Pref Pane to sync with Address Book.  Why doesn't Plaxo use an Exchange server? (since Address Book supports this)

Anyone have any ideas why one approach is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X didn't have Exchange support until 10.6 (Snow Leopard), so they probably want to support older versions of OS X. Also, then they'd have to buy an Exchange server, or force others to do so.